# Add content to a render array in a content type from my custom module

Tags: 7, nodes

I created a content type that is used to display a list of videos hosted on brightcove. I have a module that is setting a cookie for the anonymous user when they watch one. My end goal is to display a viewed/unviewed icon for the user on the list.

I have all the data I need in the cookie. I just need to create a module that reads the cookie data and edits the render array for the content type. The issue is I am not sure how to add new values to that content type's render array. Is there a hook I can use to get access to the specific content type to add a key/value for viewed/unviewed? This is for drupal 7.

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`hook_node_view()`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!node!node.api.php/function/hook_node_view/7) was made for exactly that:

> Act on a node that is being assembled before rendering.

e.g.

```
function MYMODULE_node_view($node, $view_mode, $langcode) {
  if ($node->type == 'my_type' && $view_mode == 'full') {
    if (in_array($node->nid, $_SESSION['viewed_videos'])) {
      $node->content['viewed'] = array(
        '#markup' => t('You have viewed this video'),
        '#weight' => 10,
      );
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: looks good to me. I will be playing with this. Thanks!